# Authenticating file movements in Lion

Tags: macos

Why do I have to authenticate moving every file and folder into my hard drive -- where I store all of my files?  It's a pain!

Comment: Can you post screenshots or similar to help us in understanding the problem? Do you have admin rights? Are you moving files inside your home folder or somewhere else?

Comment: Please put some effort in formulating your problem/question. You are hardly giving any info at all.

Answer (score 1):

Cause maybe you're not an admin and the admin is protecting his main disk. Could you provide more information about who you are (user-wise of course: admin, normal user,...) and which files you are trying to move and to what (internal, external,...)